# Does app size on device equal final size in app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store

I uploaded my app to iTunes Connect, what I see under "compressed file size" is 222MB. However, when I check the app size on a real device in settings->general->storage, it shows 84.9 MB. Why am I seeing two different sizes here, and which one is correct? If either is accurate, how can I estimate the app size before I submit to app store? I'm trying to reduce the size to max 100 MB so that users can download and instal over cellular. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: No I did not. I don't have too many images.

Comment: is there any size limitation while uplaoding app on app store? my app size is 150MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your app's page on iTunes Connect, select the "Activity" tab, select a build and you'll see a link that says "App Store File Sizes":

[image: App Store File Sizes]

Click it and you'll get estimated sizes for different devices.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Is there a way to see which files take up too much space?

Comment: Run this in the Terminal: `unzip -lv /path/to/your/app.ipa`. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html. You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to estimate the size of the app for different form factors because Apple uses a method called [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html). I think the best way to do that is to check on the every platform on yourself. Or keep the initial package size to less then 100MB.